# svg не отображается в браузере Chrome

Tags: svg

Хочу на сайте добавить svg, для этого написал

```
<img src="images/use_maximum.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Проблема в том, что в Firefox и IE данная конструкция работает, а в Chrome нет.  В браузере в место картинки пустота, хотя в DOM элемент есть. Подскажите, как исправить.

Comment: Что в SVG файле?

Comment: обычная картинка

Comment: Обычная показалась бы. Покажите картинку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы хотите реально получить помощь в решении вашей проблемы, то необходимо давать максимально возможное количество информации. Прежде всего нужен код вашего SVG изображения.

- А сейчас остается только гадать, так как вы привели один из
  [многочисленных способов](http://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047#img-p)  добавления svg в HTML.  И этот способ
  работает во всех браузерах включая `IE11`, при нахождении svg
  изображения, как локально, так и удаленно.

**Пример загрузки внешнего svg**

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/WikiProject_Zoo_Logo.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
```

- Если у вас локальный файл svg нормально отображается в браузерах, но
  не виден в вашей HTML страничке, то может стоит поискать ошибки в
  верстке?

**Ниже пример респонсивного svg**

```css
div .img-responsive{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-responsive">
<svg viewBox="0 0 852 438">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/WikiProject_Zoo_Logo.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня был проблема в сохранении SVG в Иллюстраторе. Вот параметры при которых svg стал отображаться.[image: Сохранение svg из Иллюстратора]

Answer (score 0):

нужно указать тип,       к примеру        type="image/svg+xml"